# Adoptable SD card in Nougat

Tags: internal-sd, 7.0-nougat, adoptable-storage

I have recently formatted my SD card as adoptable/internal storage in android nougat 7.0. There is a option of ejecting the card. My question is, if I eject the card, would I be able to use it by a card reader, or would the data be corrupted/deleted?

Comment: You won't be able to read it as it's encrypted now. For details, see our [adoptable-storage tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adoptable-storage/info) and follow its pointers.

Answer (score 1):

- Your card cannot be read by a card reader, as it is *encrypted* , when you converted it to internal or adoptable-storage. This encryption covers your device (internal storage) and SD. You can read more about that in [adoptable-storage](/questions/tagged/adoptable-storage) [wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adoptable-storage/info)
- If you eject the card, data is not corrupted on the card, but as [Izzy pointed out](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/167116/adoptable-sd-card-in-nougat/167119?noredirect=1#comment213878_167119), your device would be pretty much unusable, till you re- insert

Comment: Yupp. Side-effect: if you eject the card, what will stop working until it's inserted again? As it's "internal storage", there shouldn't remain much in "working state" without the card :)

Comment: @Izzy: Thanks for pointing that out, honestly didn't think of that, will add it